# Implementing uitable like iphone email overview

Tags: iphone, email, uitableview, interface

I have a table (UITableView) and shall implement therefore the functions like in the iphone email-interface. This means: In the header right up I need a edit-button. When pressed, some cells can be marked and in the footer there appear several buttons.

Is there a library, where I can take the functionality from? If not, any idea, how I can Implement the "marking function"?

Answer (score 0):

There's a cool example among the apple docs, which I guess meets well your request. Inspect it, I think you'll find much useful there:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913